# External hard drive "too big" for file transfer

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, formatting

I recently purchased a Samsung T7 Shield with a 4TB capacity to transfer surgical videos to from a Steris operating room camera. My computer is a MacBook Pro. I have been unable to transfer the videos and the IT person at the hospital is saying that they have had issues with hard drives that are "too big." We were able to successfully transfer files to 4 GB jump drives, one formatted in NTFS and the other in exFAT. Here is what I have done thus far:

1. Formatted T7 in exfAT format without the password protection from the Samsung app. Result: The surgical computer system did not recognize the hard drive.
2. Added password protection to the T7 using the Samsung app. The computer system recognized the video but would not successfully transfer videos to the drive.
3. Partitioned the T7 with one of the partitions being 4 GB in size (like the thumb drive). Without password protection, the system would not recognize the T7 as in trial 1. With password protection on, it would recognize the T7 but not transfer, just like in trial 2.
4. Repeated trial 3 but with the larger partition formatted in APFS or Mac OS in hopes that the computer system would ignore that drive and try to write to the smaller drive. Got the same results as in trial 3.

Of note, when I used the Samsung app on the MacBook to put password protection on the T7 and then put the T7 on another computer, it would recognize the drive but only a small 60 MB segment of it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: So the camera is attached to a PC, right?  Which version of Windows or Linux does the PC run?   Or is it an embedded system?  They often have issues with the latest protocols and largest drives (40 years after the 32MB limit on hard drives, we're still having problems like that...)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I believe it is an embedded system but I can call the company tomorrow and find out more. The videos themselves are about 2 GB in size and transferred w/o difficulty to 4 GB jump drives (one formatted in NFTS, the other in exFAT).

Comment: Samsung protection might be causing the issue.  You might format the whole drive as just one partition. My choice would be NTFS, since that worked on the 4 GB drive, and it is a journaling system. If password protection is a requirement, try VeraCrypt, available for Mac (https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/log/src/Setup/MacOSX), Linux and Windows OS. The software need not reside on the external disk.

Comment: Another common limit is 2TB. You may have to switch to using smaller drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having no documentation whatsoever for the Steris operating room camera, my first guess is that it does not recognize the GPT ("GUID Partition Map") *partition table* format that is used on disks above 2TiB. In other words, the camera doesn't even know where the partitions are or how large they are, much less the filesystem types.

Try to reinitialize the disk with an MBR partition table ("[Erase](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/erase-and-reformat-a-storage-device-dskutl14079/22.0/mac/13.0)" the whole device and select "Master Boot Record" partition scheme in Disk Utility). If it's a 512e disk, this will limit it to 2TiB total, but at least it will be recognized by literally anything.

(If that solves the problem, it is possible to have a "hybrid" GPT/MBR partitioning setup where GPT-capable systems see multiple partitions and can use the whole 4TB total while MBR-only systems see a smaller subset, but you'll need to fiddle around with the "gdisk" tool to make that work.)

A second similar problem is that some large disks use 4kB logical sectors instead of the traditional 512B. This might be done by manufacturers specifically to allow the use of MBR partitioning above 2TiB (as the MBR limits come from logical sector count, not byte count, and larger sectors = fewer of them), but at the same time it can really confuse systems that have been written with the assumption of 512-byte sectors.

If this turns out to be the problem, some disks have firmwares that can be configured to report either 512b or 4K logical sectors, but in most cases that's not something you can change.

Comment: I can’t definitively say if either of these were the mechanism of the issue, but I can say that switching to a 2TB T7 Shield resolved the issue. I was unable to format the drive with the MBR scheme; I got an error saying the drive was too big. Thank you for the help.